# OpenFL and Lime does not run, because of a segmentation fault

Tags: segmentation-fault, haxe, openfl, neko, haxelib

Recently, I have found (on Mac OS X Mavericks) OpenFL and LIME (with the command line tools) not working due to a 'segmentation fault'.

Before I get into the details, here's some background.

- I originally got Haxe + Neko from the installer provided from OpenFL's site.
- I installed OpenFL from the instructions there.
- Later, when using standard Haxe coding I needed Neko but it wasn't installed apparently.
- I installed Neko from Neko's site.

And now, I get this error when typing `lime` or `openfl` or using any of their functions (e.g. building):

```
Called from lime/utils/ByteArray.hx line 109
Called from lime/system/System.hx line 286
Called from lime/system/System.hx line 405
Uncaught exception - Segmentation fault
```

Anyways, I don't know if the background has anything to do with it. I looked on the Ubuntu forums but nothing there worked for me. Any help would be appreciated; I can't find much in 'similar questions' or anywhere else for that matter.

Haxe Compiler 3.1.3 + OpenFL 3.0.0 beta. (According to `haxelib upgrade` descriptions.)

Comment: It looks like the lime ndll files aren't found on your system. What do you get if you run `haxelib path lime`?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, time difference. Anyways, I get                                   `$ haxelib path lime`
`-L lime/2,3,0/ndll/`
`/usr/lib/haxe/lib/lime/2,3,0/`
`-D lime`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neko is failing to initialize on your computer. When Lime loads up it tries calling `neko_init` in lime.ndll and crashes. It could be caused by multiple things so here are a few steps to check.

1. Typing `neko` in the terminal should display version information. Make sure it says 2.0.0 before continuing. You can also display where neko is executing from with the command `which neko`. It is typically a symbolic link from `/usr/lib/neko/neko` to `/usr/bin/neko`.
2. The std.ndll file may not be found. Usually this file and the other standard neko ndll files are located in `/usr/lib/neko`. Make sure you have a `NEKOPATH` environment variable pointing to that directory.
3. If the above seems to be correct you may want to completely remove Haxe and Neko and reinstall. Instead of using the installer from OpenFL's site you may have better luck with the one from [haxe.org](http://haxe.org/download/). It should have neko bundled with the installer version.

Comment: Just for clarification, would `export NEKOPATH=/usr/lib/neko` within the ~/.bash_profile be a proper NEKOPATH? After both 1 and 2 were corrected I uninstalled Neko and Haxe with commands from [link](https://gist.github.com/nbrew/5585878). Reinstalled with the installer from the official Haxe website. Afterwards, after `haxelib install openfl`, when running `haxelib run openfl setup`, it installs lime 2.3.0 and fails exactly like above. Any help there?
**EDIT:** In fact, it turns out that the installer OpenFL's site links to is the exact same as Haxe's.

Comment: Yep, `export NEKOPATH=/usr/lib/neko` is fine. If it's still failing you might want to post on the [OpenFL forums](http://community.openfl.org/). Someone there may know more about what is causing this issue.

Just out of curiosity have you run `haxelib selfupdate` to update haxelib?

Comment: No, I didn't run that. After I did, however, it attempted installing OpenFL 2.2.8 instead of the beta. It again failed at `haxelib run openfl setup`. I will try my luck at the OpenFL forums, thanks for the advice.